# Is it correct to say "In case of high demand we may be open for longer" to indicate optional prolonged work hours?

Tags: phrase-request, phrases

My brother runs a night club, and he asked me how would one say in English that a night club may close later if there are still lots of customers, in a way to put this on a plaque with working hours?

I have thought of "In case of high demand we may be open for longer" or "In case of high demand we may close later”. I don't want to state "we work until the last visitor", because "last visitor" may never leave under certain conditions, which wouldn't make the staff happy :)

I am not so sure about "high demand" really meaning "lots of customers". Is it clear right away, or it can be misunderstood?

Is there any better, shorter, or commonly used way to say the same?

Comment: It's OK, but it sounds overly businessy. {my coinage}. We'd just say: If there are still a lot of customers, or if there are still a lot of people waiting to get in.

Comment: "High demand" sounds odd in this context. Maybe try _"On busy nights we may close later than usual"_ or _"On busy nights we may be open longer than usual"_

Comment: @Lambie, this is a plaque, so it would make sense to keep it short, so visitors would actually pay attention to it. The longer the phrase is, the smaller letter it would be printed in, which makes it less likely somebody would notice it.

Comment: @SteveES, I like it

Comment: On busy nights is fine. But none of this has anything to do with English, I am sure all that exists in the OP's own language.

Comment: @Lambie, why so? Result would be bilingual - in both English and local language.

Comment: I'd just say *Open until **at least** X o'clock [every night]*.

Comment: The question is not an English question. If you can say in your language, on busy nights, it is likely as short as in English. I say likely. Ergo, this is not about English, really because  you had not formulated your idea in your own language before asking the question.

Comment: @Lambie, so is this SE is only for concepts that cannot be expressed in other languages? I don't agree with you then. I have asked for a concept that can be expressed in English, but in an overly verbose way that is not appropriate to be "published", and may sound odd. So, I asked for help, and provided what I came up with. Would it be better to provide an example in other language first? Weird thing about this is that the sign would be in English & Polish, and I don't speak Polish, my native language is Ukrainian, so what language should examples be in?

Comment: @SteveES, could you please make your comment an answer? I'd like to accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"High demand" sounds odd in this context; it is more commonly found in I.T. contexts, or when there is demand for a *thing*, rather than a lot of people inside a venue.

For lots of people inside a venue, **busy** would be a much more common word used to describe the situation.

> **Busy**
>   *adjective*
>   A busy place is full of activity or people

<sup>[Cambridge Dictionary - definition A2](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/busy)</sup>

Also, you might want to add *"than usual"* to the end, to make it clearer when you are closing later than.

Maybe try:

- *"On busy nights we may close later than usual"* or
- *"On busy nights we may be open longer than usual"*

Answer (score 0):

Why state a reason to stay open later?  You can simply have a plaque that reads:

> Closing hours may vary
>
> Closing hours subject to change without notice

That way if there's another reason you close later, or if you want to close earlier, you've already posted notice (which no one will likely read, but that's a different problem).

Or you can have fun with it:

> Open 'til the last man standing, isn't.

Answer (score 0):

If the sign is for customers, you might use

> If you keep us busy, we tend to close later.
>
> We close a half hour after the Last Rounds Bell (whenever that is...)

if you want to encourage the patrons to keep ordering drinks.

As a gimmick, *regulars* will know you will stay open later.